# Degree of trigonometric polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, trigonometry

How can i determine degree of trigonometric polynomial? I know the highest power in a univariate polynomial is known as its degree, but what is degree of trigonometric polynomial? Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by *trigonometric polynomial?*  Can you give a definition or perhaps some examples and non-examples?

Comment: cosine and sine functions

Comment: $\cos 2 x \equiv 2 \cos^2 x - 1$. The left-hand side looks like a first-degree trig polynomial to me, but the right-hand side looks second-degree. How does this affect your question? (Note that if you express the value in terms of $x/2$, you get "fourth-degree", and so on.)

Comment: Are you building polynomial expressions out of sines and cosines, such as $2\sin^2t - 3\sin t \cos t + 1$?

Comment: yes,for example $$2\sin{3x} + 3\sin{2x}$$

Answer (score 5):

To determine the degree of an algebraic polynomial, we bring to to the canonical form $$c_0+c_1 x+c_2 x^2+ \dots +c_nx^n\tag{1}$$ with $c_n$ not equal to $0$. The number $n$ is  the degree of this polynomial.

To determine the degree of an trigonometric polynomial, we also bring to to the canonical form 
$$a_0+ a_1 \cos x+b_1\sin x  +  a_2 \cos 2x+b_2 \sin 2x  + \dots + a_n\cos nx+b_n \sin nx \tag{2}$$ with at least one of $a_n,b_n$ not equal to zero.  The number $n$ is  the degree of this trigonometric polynomial.

Alternatively, you can write (2)  in complex form, as a sum of $c_ke^{ikx}$, $c_k \in\mathbb C$. Then the degree is  the maximum of $|k|$ among the terms with $c_k\ne 0$. This is closer to (1), especially because $e^{ikx}$ is $e^{ix}$ *raised to power* $k$.